# Expo React Native Simulator Error: Facebook SDK has not been initialized yet

Tags: facebook, react-native, expo

I'm getting this "Error: Facebook SDK has not been initialized yet" my code below is...

My package.json file configuration information:

```
    {
      "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
       "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
       "eject": "expo eject"
        },
       "dependencies": {
       "expo": "^36.0.0",
       "firebase": "^7.8.2",
       "react": "16.9.0",
       "react-dom": "16.9.0",
       "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz",
       "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
       "expo-facebook": "~8.0.0"
       },
    "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
    },
   "private": true
    }
```

My Code:

```
   import React from 'react';
   import { StyleSheet, 
   Text, 
   View, 
   TouchableHighlight, 
   TextInput} from 'react-native';
   import { f, auth, database } from './config/config';
   import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';


   export default class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(props)
   {

   super(props);
   this.state = {
   loggedin: false
   };
   //this.registerUser('testemailaddress@gmail.com',                                                                              
       'fakepassword');var that = this;
   f.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if(user) {
   //Logged in
  that.setState({
  loggedin: true
 });
 console.log('Logged in', user);
 }else{
//Logged out
that.setState({
loggedin: false
});
 console.log('Logged out');
}
 });
}

loginUser = async(email, pass) => {
 if(email != '' && pass != '') {
 //
   try{
   let user = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,          
    pass); console.log(user);
 }catch(error) {
   console.log(error);
 }
 }else{
 //if they are empty
 alert('Missing email or password');
 }
}
async loginWithFacebook (){

const{ type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
'APP_ID',
{ permissions: ['public_profile'] }
 );

  if(type === 'success'){
  const credentials =      f.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
   f.auth().signInWithCredential(credentials).catch((error) => {
     console.log('Error...', error);

   });

   }
  }


  registerUser = (email, password) => {

console.log(email, password);
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then((userObj) => console.log(email,password, userObj))
.catch((error) => console.log('error logging in', error));

   }

 signUserOut = () => {
auth.signOut()
.then(() => {
 console.log('Logged out...');
}).catch((error) => {
console.log('Error', error);
  });
 }

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    <Text>---------</Text>
    { this.state.loggedin == true ? (
    <View>
    <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={ () => this.signUserOut()}
    style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <Text> Log Out</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <Text> Logged in...</Text>
    </View>
  ) : (
    <View>

    { this.state.emailloginView == true ? (


      <View>
        <Text>Email:</Text>
        <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}
        value={this.state.email} />

      <Text>Password:</Text>
        <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({pass: text})}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        value={this.state.pass}
         />

    <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={ () =>  this.loginUser(this.state.email,this.state.pass)}
    style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <Text> Login</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>

    ) : (
      <View></View>
    )}

  <TouchableHighlight 
  onPress={() => this.setState({emailloginView: true})}
  style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
  <Text style={{color:'white'}}> Login With Email</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>

  <TouchableHighlight 
  onPress={() => this.loginWithFacebook()}
  style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
  <Text style={{color:'white'}}> Login With Facebook</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
  )}
</View>
  );
    }
    }
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I'm using the built-in IOS simulator and physical iPhone 7 plus to run my expo React Native app. I've been dealing with this error since yesterday. Can someone please help me?

Error Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling logInWitReadPermissions you need to add

```
Facebook.initializeAsync(appId, appName);
```

As stated in  [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/#facebookinitializeasyncappid-string--undefined-appname-string-)

> Facebook.initializeAsync(appId: string | undefined, appName: string |
>   undefined): Promise Calling this method ensures that the SDK is
>   initialized. You have to call this method before calling
>   logInWithReadPermissionsAsync to ensure that Facebook support is
>   initialized properly. You may or may not provide an optional appId:
>   string argument. If you don't provide it, Facebook SDK will try to use
>   appId from native app resources (which in standalone apps you would
>   define in app.json, in Expo client are unavailable and in bare you
>   configure yourself according to Facebook setup documentation for iOS
>   and Android). If it fails to find one, the promise will be rejected.
>   If you provide an explicit appId, it will override any other source.
>   The same resolution mechanism works for appName.